# Join 3 tables with different column names

Tags: mysql, database, join, union

I have an event software. There is a table for individuals who sign up to an event
and a table for teams that sign up to an event. Both individuals and teams can sign up to the same event. I also have a shirt table. This table will relate a shirt to an individual or a shirt to a team and shirts for teams will have multiple rows because teams are more than 1 individual. Here is the structure.

```
Individuals
-id
-event_id
-member_id

Teams
-id
-event_id
-team_name

shirts
-id
-entity_id
-shirt_id
-is_team
```

At first I had a separate individual shirt table and a separate team shirt table and tried to `union all` them to no avail. So now I have a single shirt table with the `entity_id` being either the individual id or the team id and the `is_team` to designate which table.

I'm struggling with a `join` to somehow get all the shirts for individuals and teams based on the `event_id`. I would have to show all the individual shirts and all the team shirts.

I can paste the `union` statement for my other table structure but I have nothing for the `join` to show. I'm just looking for a step in the right direction.

Comment: what is the relation between shirts Individuals and shirts to teams in other words what is the common key bet them ?

Comment: I think thats the problem. The individual is one person so the shirt table will have 1 row for each. The teams are 2 or more so the shirt table will have a row for each team member. The entity_id is the individual id or the team id, if that makes sense.

Comment: and is_team in the shirt table is set if the entry is for team which is 0 for individual and 1 for team ?

Comment: correct, its a boolean to signify if its from the individual or team table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you probably need

```
select s.id,
s.shirt_id,
case 
 when s.is_team = 0 then i.member_id 
 else
 t.team_name 
END
as entity
from shirts s
left join Individuals i on i.id = s.entity_id AND s.is_team = 0
left join Teams t on t.id = s.entity_id AND s.is_team = 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbb687/5

Comment: That works, thank you. Now is that still the table structure to  use for say, if I then need to group by a team? Basically would you recommend this over 2 separate shirt tables, one for individual shirts and one for team shirts using a union?

Comment: yes further normalization is much better and u can easily use UNION. Thats a better approach and shirts table will be free from such complex relations.

Comment: Ah okay, I appreciate it and I'll go with the union and separate tables.

Comment: well u can do this with the above query also check here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbb687/6